# ReCall iframe after setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wish popup box (iframe colorbox) keep available even after setInterval running. But in fact, only the first iframe actually can pop up, the next after 2 seconds, bring me to my requested page. (sorry for bad english)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"400px", height:"600px"});

            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
             $('#chatting').load("<?php echo current_url() ?> #chatting") ;
             $("#iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"400px", height:"600px"});
            }, 2000);


          });
        </script>

           <div id="chatting">
                <li class="chat-list">
                    <div class="chat-body">
                        <a id="iframe"href="intern/public_chat/test.php">XXX</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
```

I need every reload time (2 seconds as setinterval), updated value keep can using iframe colorbox.

But only it's always bring me to my requested page but not in pop up box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"500px", height:"600px"});

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     $('#chatting').load("<?php echo current_url() ?> #chatting", function() {
         $("#iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"500px", height:"600px"});
     }) ;
    }, 2000);


  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

look at your anchor tag 
`<a id="iframe" href="intern/public_chat/test.php</a>`

i just improve and it's work
`<a id="iframe" href="intern/public_chat/test.php"> </a>`

Comment: actually i just miss my typing, the actual one is : <a id="iframe" href="intern/public_chat/test.php> xxx </a> ... still have the same problem, dude ...